# Webclient doesnt like UrlEncoded slash. How to make it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webclient, .net-2.0

I'm trying to pass an URL to an API using a .net 2.0 webclient (unable to upgrade). The webclient call only works if there are no slashes in the encoded value. Any idea why it is failing and how to make it work?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace ConsoleAppWebClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/xml";
                var requestUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://www.somewebsite.com");
                var stringResult = client.DownloadString("https://localhost:12345/api/getstuff/" + requestUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above doesnt work but the below works just fine

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace ConsoleAppWebClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/xml";
                var requestUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https:www.somewebsite.com");
                var stringResult = client.DownloadString("https://localhost:12345/api/getstuff/" + requestUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `requestUrl` is meant to be a query parameter, but you're adding it to the URL's path.

The result is

> https://localhost:12345/api/getstuff/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somewebsite.com

"%" is an unsafe character which can lead to unpredictable results.

Instead, try making it a querystring parameter:

```cs
var requestUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https:www.somewebsite.com");
var stringResult = client.DownloadString(
    "https://localhost:12345/api/getstuff/?requestUrl=" + requestUrl);
```

Now that the URL-encoded parameter is in the querystring instead of the path it should be okay.

Comment: I have exactly his problem, but alas, your suggestion doesn't help me because the API concerned isn't supporting the provision of the the requestUrl in the example above as a querystring parameter, by only in as a part of the request path itself. It's the GitLab API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository

Comment: It looks like the API requires this in the path, but apparently it handles the % character. It shows a sample URL: `https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=master`. Apparently if you URL-encode the file_path part it's supposed to handle it.

Comment: This makes me wonder about my original answer. It seemed easier to solve the problem by moving the parameter to the querystring since this was an API the OP was writing, so they had control over it. While it's documented that % is an unsafe character, apparently the GitLab API allows it.

Comment: I do URL encode the file path and the URL works fine with curl, and oddly, and this is twilight zone material, if I use that in a C# DLL which I load into a .exe it work, but if I use that same DLL as part of an ASP website under IIS or IIS express, then the server receives the URL decoded, it no longer see the %2F it sees / and the GitLab API returns 404. Perplexing .NET behavior that seems context dependent (same code, same DLL, linked in a .exe does not decode the URL before transmission, loaded by IIS decodes the URL before transmission.

Comment: Only solution I found for this BTW was to use the GraphQL API that GitLab offers.